# jQuery - How to select only images that are wrapped in links?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to select only images wrapped in links so I can the rel="lightbox" to the links. I've tried with 2 loops but it doesn't work as it adds the rel attribute to normal links too (without images).

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('#floorplans img').each(function() {
    $('#floorplans a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel','lightbox[floorplans]'); 
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$('#floorplans a img')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a better solution could be:

```
$('#floorplans a:has(img)').attr('rel', 'lightbox[floorplans]');
```

why its better?

Guffa's solution will select all the images inside anchors into a jQuery set (which can be a big overkill, if you have a large number of images in the page).

My solution will only select the specified anchors, and not the images.

Comment: Understood. Thank you! One question though: Can I optimize this or is it already as optimized as it can be if I have 2 divs?
`$('#floorplans a:has(img)').attr('rel', 'lightbox[floorplans]');

$('#gallery a:has(img)').attr('rel', 'lightbox[gallery]');`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to loop to do that (and also, your outer loop is useless as you don't use it's result in any way). You can use a selector to find images inside links, then use the `closest` method to find each link, and then you can let the `attr` method loop through the result and set the attribute on all of them:

```
$('#floorplans a img').closest('a').attr('rel','lightbox[floorplans]');
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! I've tried with parent instead of closest and that works too -  but I wonder what's the difference... :)

Answer (score 1):

$("a > #MyImage")

http://jsfiddle.net/dbvSp/